# Pandas - check if subset of dataframe is in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe which I'll call 'names':

```
date       name    code  
6/1/2018   A       5     
6/1/2018   B       5     
7/1/2018   A       5     
7/1/2018   B       5
```

I have the following df which I need to alter:

```
date       name    comment   
5/1/2018   A       'Good'    
6/1/2018   A       'Good'    
6/1/2018   B       'Good'    
6/1/2018   C       'Good'    
7/1/2018   A       'Good'    
7/1/2018   B       'Good'
```

I need to change the comment to 'Bad' if the name isn't in the names dataframe *for that date*

Right now I have:

```
df['comment'] = np.where(~df['name'].isin(names['name']), 'Bad', df['comment'])
```

Though obviously that doesn't work because it doesn't take into account name AND date.

Final output:

```
date       name    comment   
5/1/2018   A       'Bad'     
6/1/2018   A       'Good'    
6/1/2018   B       'Good'    
6/1/2018   C       'Bad'     
7/1/2018   A       'Good'    
7/1/2018   B       'Good'
```

The first row was changed because there's no A entry for 5/1 in the names dataframe. The C row was changed because there's no C entry for 6/1 in the names df (or rather no C entry at all).

Note: Both dataframes (names and df) are larger than I've shown, both row and column-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performant solution using [`pd.Index.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
v = names.set_index(['date', 'name'])
m = v.index.get_indexer(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.date, df.name])) == -1
df.loc[m, 'comment'] = '\'Bad\''

print(df)
      date name comment
0  5/1/2018    A   'Bad'
1  6/1/2018    A  'Good'
2  6/1/2018    B  'Good'
3  6/1/2018    C   'Bad'
4  7/1/2018    A  'Good'
5  7/1/2018    B  'Good'
```

---

Alternatively, do a LEFT OUTER [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), determine missing values in the right DataFrame, and use that to [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) rows:

```
m = df.merge(names, how='left', on=['date', 'name']).code.isna()
df['comment'] = df['comment'].mask(m, '\'Bad\'')

print(df)
       date name comment
0  5/1/2018    A   'Bad'
1  6/1/2018    A  'Good'
2  6/1/2018    B  'Good'
3  6/1/2018    C   'Bad'
4  7/1/2018    A  'Good'
5  7/1/2018    B  'Good'
```

Comment: Would it make a difference if my np.where clause was actually more like df['comment'] = np.where((~df['name'].isin(names['name']) & (df['src'] == 'Table1')), 'Bad', df['comment']). Essentially it can't just be a straight-up merge.

Comment: @JesusMonroe Hmm, see my edits? I've added more options for you.

Comment: @JesusMonroe I think using `isin` (as you are doing) is incorrect here, because you could still get True even if the (date, name) pair doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Adding hyperlinks to the answer is tedious, but simple, done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) followed by [`pd.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
idx_cols = ['date', 'name']
mask = df.set_index(idx_cols).index.isin(names.set_index(idx_cols).index)

df['comment'].where(mask, '\'Bad\'', inplace=True)

print(df)

       date name comment
0  5/1/2018    A   'Bad'
1  6/1/2018    A  'Good'
2  6/1/2018    B  'Good'
3  6/1/2018    C   'Bad'
4  7/1/2018    A  'Good'
5  7/1/2018    B  'Good'
```